# Simple virtual machine in Rust

Tags: rust, virtual-machine

### About

I'm trying to implement a simple virtual machine. Now it supports only three operations:

- `ADD(reg0, reg1, reg2) -> reg0 = reg1 + reg2`
- `LOAD(reg, value) -> reg = value`
- `EXIT -> finish process`

It has 8 registers and no memory (for now).

### Source code

**main.rs**:

```
use std::process;

mod opcodes;
mod utils;

const REGISTERS_COUNT: usize = 8;

#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
struct Program<'a> {
    code: &'a Vec<u8>,
    pos: usize
}

impl<'a> Program<'a> {
    pub fn new(code: &'a Vec<u8>) -> Program<'a> {
        Program { code: code, pos: 0 }
    }

    pub fn fetch(&mut self) -> u8 {
        self.pos += 1;
        if self.pos > self.code.len() {
            process::exit(0);
        }
        return self.code[self.pos - 1];
    }
}

fn eval(mut program: Program, mut registers: [u64; REGISTERS_COUNT]) {
    loop {
        let operator = program.fetch();
        let operands = (
            program.fetch(),

            vec![
                program.fetch(), program.fetch(),
                program.fetch(), program.fetch(),
                program.fetch(), program.fetch(),
                program.fetch(), program.fetch()
            ]
        );

        match operator {
            opcodes::EXIT => {
                process::exit(0);
            }
            opcodes::LOAD => {
                registers[operands.0 as usize] = utils::concat_bytes(&operands.1);
            }
            opcodes::ADD => {
                registers[operands.0 as usize] = registers[utils::concat_bytes(&operands.1[..4]) as usize]
                    + registers[utils::concat_bytes(&operands.1[4..]) as usize];
            }
            _ => {
                println!("error: invalid instruction code");
                process::exit(1);
            }
        }

        println!("{:?}", registers);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let registers: [u64; REGISTERS_COUNT] = [0; REGISTERS_COUNT];
    let code = vec![
        opcodes::LOAD,
            0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x64,
        opcodes::LOAD,
            0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xC8,
        opcodes::ADD,
            0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01,
        opcodes::EXIT,
            0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
    ];
    let program = Program::new(&code);

    eval(program, registers);
}
```

**utils.rs**:

```
pub fn concat_bytes(bytes: &[u8]) -> u64 {
    let mut result = bytes[0] as u64;
    for i in 1..bytes.len() {
        result = (result << 8) | (bytes[i] as u64)
    }
    return result;
}
```

**opcodes.rs**:

```
pub const EXIT: u8 = 0x00;
pub const LOAD: u8 = 0x01;
pub const ADD:  u8 = 0x02;
```

### Output

```
[100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[100, 200, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[100, 200, 300, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

### Disadvantages:

- No memory
- Only integers
- All operators require the same number of arguments (even if they don't need any, like `EXIT`)

Anything else?

Comment: If you'd like to see another interpreter, I've [made one for Human Resource Machine](https://github.com/shepmaster/human-resource-machine).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Document your instruction format! Looks to be opcode,
   destination, 8 bytes of input. You need to describe the endianness
   of the data though.  Comments are an OK first step, but data
   structures with self-describing names are probably even better.
2. You could avoid entire classes of errors by splitting the
   program and data memory. This is "Harvard" vs "von Neumann"
   architecture.
3. Remove unneeded type specification, such as when defining
   `registers` in `main`.
4. Can use `Default::default` to get a reasonable initial state,
   such as a vector of zeroes. Prevents having to re-type the length
   again.
5. Don't use explicit `return` statements at the end of functions.
6. What is the expected behavior if you `concat` a slice with more
   than 8 bytes? I made this limit to the first 8 bytes.
7. Become intimately familiar with the methods on `Iterator` and try to leverage the functional tools it provides, like `fold`.
8. Avoid slice indexing whenever possible. It's slightly slower as
   it performs bounds checks.
9. `concat` is a bit odd of a name. I feel that `pack` is more
   typical for this operation.
10. Your opcode is crying out to be an enum. This also happens to be
    a great place to hang behavior, such as converting it to/from an
    integer.
11. It's a little strange that `eval` accepts the program and
    registers by value. Maybe you want to create a `Machine` that owns
    them, or accept them by mutable reference?
12. It's strange that `Program` contains a pointer to where the data
    is. Typically, the program should be immutable and you'd have a
    Program Counter (PC) that tracks where you are in the program.
13. Printing the registers each iteration is a form of logging. If
    you need such a thing, inject it using a generic. In this case, I
    just accepted a generic function type, but you could also create
    your own trait if you wanted more granular places to log.
14. You should basically never use a `&Vec<T>`; use `&[T]` instead.
15. You should basically never use `process:exit` inside of any
    function but `main`; use proper error handling like `Option` or
    `Result`. I usually start with `expect` on these types which will
    `panic` the program, then thread the errors through once the
    general structure is in place.
16. Use `slice::get` instead of checking the length manually.
17. Creating a `fetch_many` method allows better naming,
    flexibility, and a more efficient implementation.
18. Create more types! For example, create a `RegisterFile` and
    `Arguments` to offload some of the decision making and
    implementation details. These types provide naming (which is
    self-documentation), extra seams for types and assertions, as well
    as places to put "helper" methods (e.g. `pack_bytes`). They might
    show places where you might be misusing sizes (e.g. indexing the
    register file beyond 8-bit makes no sense).

---

```
use std::ops::{Index, IndexMut};
use std::cmp;
use std::error::Error;

enum Opcode {
    Exit = 0x00,
    Load = 0x01,
    Add  = 0x02,
}

impl Opcode {
    fn from_u8(byte: u8) -> Result<Opcode, Box<Error + Send + Sync>> {
        use Opcode::*;

        let opc = match byte {
            x if x == Exit as u8 => Exit,
            x if x == Load as u8 => Load,
            x if x == Add as u8 => Add,
            _ => return Err(From::from("invalid instruction code")),
        };

        Ok(opc)
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct RegisterFile {
    registers: [u64; 8],
}

// TODO: Consider catching and reporting access to registers outside
// of the register file. The indexing implementation panics the
// program.

impl Index<u8> for RegisterFile {
    type Output = u64;

    fn index(&self, idx: u8) -> &u64 {
        &self.registers[idx as usize]
    }
}

impl IndexMut<u8> for RegisterFile {
    fn index_mut(&mut self, idx: u8) -> &mut u64 {
        &mut self.registers[idx as usize]
    }
}

impl Default for RegisterFile {
    fn default() -> RegisterFile {
        RegisterFile { registers: Default::default() }
    }
}

#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
struct Program<'a> {
    code: &'a [u8],
    pos: usize
}

impl<'a> Program<'a> {
    pub fn new(code: &'a [u8]) -> Program<'a> {
        Program { code: code, pos: 0 }
    }

    fn fetch(&mut self) -> Result<u8, Box<Error + Send + Sync>> {
        let v = try!(self.code.get(self.pos).ok_or("No more code to read"));
        self.pos += 1;
        Ok(*v)
    }

    fn fetch_many(&mut self, n: usize) -> Result<Vec<u8>, Box<Error + Send + Sync>> {
        if self.code.len() < self.pos + n {
            return Err(From::from("No more code to read"));
        }
        let v = &self.code[self.pos..(self.pos + n)];
        self.pos += n;
        Ok(v.to_owned())
    }
}

struct Arguments {
    values: Vec<u8>,
}

impl Arguments {
    // TODO: Did I pick `high` and `low` right?
    pub fn high_u32_8(&self) -> u8 {
        self.values[3]
    }

    pub fn low_u32_8(&self) -> u8 {
        self.values[7]
    }

    pub fn u64(&self) -> u64 {
        Arguments::pack_bytes(&self.values)
    }

    fn pack_bytes(bytes: &[u8]) -> u64 {
        let len = cmp::min(bytes.len(), 8);
        bytes[..len].iter().fold(0, |acc, &byte| acc << 8 | (byte as u64))
    }
}

fn eval<F>(mut program: Program, mut registers: RegisterFile, each_iteration: F) -> Result<(), Box<Error + Send + Sync>>
    where F: Fn(&RegisterFile),
{
    loop {
        let operator = try!(program.fetch());
        let operator = try!(Opcode::from_u8(operator));
        let destination = try!(program.fetch());
        let arguments = try!(program.fetch_many(8));
        let arguments = Arguments { values: arguments };

        match operator {
            Opcode::Exit => return Ok(()),
            Opcode::Load => {
                registers[destination] = arguments.u64();
            }
            Opcode::Add => {
                registers[destination] = registers[arguments.high_u32_8()]
                    + registers[arguments.low_u32_8()];
            }
        }

        each_iteration(&registers);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let registers = Default::default();
    let code = vec![
        Opcode::Load as u8,
            0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x64,
        Opcode::Load as u8,
            0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xC8,
        Opcode::Add as u8,
            0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01,
        Opcode::Exit as u8,
            0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
    ];
    let program = Program::new(&code);

    if let Err(e) = eval(program, registers, |registers| println!("{:?}", registers)) {
        println!("Evaluation failed: {}", e);
        // TODO: Could add process::exit with an error code here
    }
}
```

Comment: "You could avoid entire classes of errors by splitting the program and data memory." → The best interpreted VMs use large register files with instructions that directly address the stack. They then effectively get a fresh register file every call. You still need a separate heap, but normally that's accessed through an allocator rather than explicit access.